# Angular Material "[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider" errors when trying to include ngMaterial $mdToast, $animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to use ngMaterial in this app:

Bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "x",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "~3",
    "angular": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.7",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13",
    "angular-ui-utils": "bower",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2",
    "angular-file-upload": "1.1.5",
    "angular-material": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": ">= 1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Config JS file:

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    lib: {
      css: [
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/angular-material.css'
      ],
      js: [
        'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
        'public/lib/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
        'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
        'public/lib/angular-material/angular-material.js',
        'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
        'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
        'public/lib/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.js'
      ],
```

App configuration:

```
// Init the application configuration module for AngularJS application
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function () {

  // Init module configuration options
  var applicationModuleName = 'x';
  var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'angularFileUpload', 'ngMaterial'];

  // Add a new vertical module
  var registerModule = function (moduleName, dependencies) {
    // Create angular module
    angular.module(moduleName, dependencies || []);

    // Add the module to the AngularJS configuration file
    angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
  };

  return {
    applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
    applicationModuleVendorDependencies: applicationModuleVendorDependencies,
    registerModule: registerModule
  };
})();
```

And then:

```
// Use Application configuration module to register a new module
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('core');
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('core.admin', ['core']);
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('core.admin.routes', ['ui.router']);
```

It fails when I try to reference ngMaterial, $mdToast or $animate in the module like below. Without the references below there are no errors on html md- references, they just don't work properly (they will display but without 'material' functionality).

Controller JS file:

```
angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', '$state', 'ngMaterial', 'Authentication', 'Menus', 
  function ($scope, $state, Authentication, Menus) {
// Add '$mdToast', '$animate',   $mdToast, $animate and the same error results
```

Throws error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngMaterialProvider <- ngMaterial <- HeaderController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=ngMaterialProvider%20%3C-%20ngMaterial%20%3C-%20HeaderController
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4289:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4294:45
    at getService (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
    at extend.instance (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:9136:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:8248:36)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:7680:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:7555:30) <header data-ng-include="'/modules/core/views/header.client.view.html'" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ngMaterial` is the name of the module, it can't be injected in the controller. You have to remove it from the following lines:

```
angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', 
    ['$scope', '$state', 'ngMaterial', 'Authentication', 'Menus',  
    function ($scope, $state, Authentication, Menus) {
```

Instead, `ngMaterial` should be added in the module dependencies of your app:

```
angular.module('appName', [..., 'ngMaterial', ...])
```

Then you can inject angular-material components, like `$mdToast`, in you controller.

Comment: Thank you, so ngMaterial should not be referenced there and the directives should be working without it? Am I missing any other steps before using the directives? Initially I only referenced '$mdToast', '$animate' and they threw the same errors - should they be there? Thank you very much for the quick response!

Comment: Once you add `ngMaterial` in the module dependencies of your app, you can inject `$mdToast` in your directive.

Comment: Ah, thank you! ngMaterial is referenced in the app configuration (added above) but something there is obviously not working. Thanks again for the very clear explanation.

Comment: I see the edit. You must also have a line, *somewhere*, where you actually call the `registerModule` function with parameters. Can you add this line?

Comment: If you look carefully at the application declaration you have, you can notice `ngMaterial` is referenced in an array named `applicationModuleVendorDependencies`. This array is returned by the *configuration object*, but not a fact that it is passed to `angular.module` function, i.e. to your `registerModule` function that is also returned by the *config object*.

Comment: Added the function call. So I need to add 'ngMaterial' as a parameter in the call ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('core');? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: That would solve the problem for `ngMaterial`, but I guess you are using other dependencies. Better reuse the array of dependencies you defined: `ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('core', ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleVendorDependencies);`